# What can a Cleric actually summon with their Summon Monster spells?

Tags: spells, cleric

I'm a relative newbie to D&D, and am playing a level 3 neutral good cleric.  I would LOVE to use the spells to summon a monster, but am not certain what kind of monsters can be summoned.  How does this work?

Comment: Could you please add the edition of D&D you are playing to the tags? There's some differences between them that could be relevant.

Comment: Yeah, please do let us know which edition of D&D you're playing. Otherwise we can only answer you generally, and that's going to be less useful to you.

Comment: You can add more tags by pressing the "edit" button under your question; as Jonathan and Grubermensch have said already, it's important to specify which version of D&D you're playing since the 5 of them have diferent rules.

Comment: Also, in most of the editions the list of summonable monsters is right in the spell description...

Comment: In the editions where the list of summonable monsters is elsewhere, it's (as far as I remember) in the Monster/Monstrous Manual, in the appendices.

Comment: In pathfinder this is a goodish question: some splatbooks and modules add summonable monsters to the list.